# global variable where variable has members

Tags: powershell, global-variables

I want to open a Microsoft Access DB in a PowerShell function. I'll store the connection variable in the main code.

This is the code:

```
Function open_database($dbname) {
  # Open the database
  try
  {
    $global:conn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=$dbname;Persist Security Info=False"
    $global:conn.Open()
  }
  catch
  {
    write-host "Error connecting to the database " + $dbname
    return $false
  }
  return $true
}

# M A I N
$conn = New-Object System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection
if (-Not (open_database("C:\temp\mydb.mdb"))) {exit}
```

I get this error message:

> Error connecting to the database  + C:\temp\mydb.mdb
>   The property 'ConnectionString' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists and can be set.

How do I fix this?

I think PowerShell is associating `global` with `conn` and not global with `conn.ConnectionString`.

Comment: But the code in your question doesn't give that error ? I don't have an access database handy, but it doesn't error, it runs without complaint. And it should, if I can put test code in a comment - `function test { $global:c.x=4 }; $c=@{x=2}; $c; test; $c` accessing a property of a global does work.

Comment: I'd try omitting all the `Try_Catch` structures for debugging purposes. Use bare _inner_  of the `Try` block and then `return $false` to see _full specification_ of possible  errors. Is `$global:conn` defined as expected? `$conn = …` at `#main` is defined in the _script_ scope. Is the OLEDB provider registered? …

Answer (score 0):

I don't have Access available at the moment, but modifying global variables in a nested context is a flawed concept anyway. It's better to create the connection in your function and have it either return the connection object or throw an exception:

```
function open_database($dbname) {
  $cn = New-Object System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection
  $cn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" +
                         "Data Source=$dbname;" +
                         "Persist Security Info=False"
  $cn.Open() | Out-Null
  return $cn
}

try {
  $conn = open_database 'C:\temp\mydb.mdb'
} catch {
  Write-Host "Error connecting to the database $dbname"
  exit 1
}
```

That way you're not mixing contexts, and you only do error handling once.